# Always Got Error while accessing Json Data for my windows Phone Apps

Tags: ajax, json, windows-phone-7

Following Code is not working for my windows Application.
It Always returns "system.collections.generic.dictionary 2 system.string system.object" Error.
I tried replacing json with text and it returns successful but invalid data.

`$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
                url     :$(this).attr('action'),
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : {
                            'action' : $('#action').val(),
                            'user' : $.trim($('#user_id').val()),
                            'password' : $.trim($('#password').val())

                          },
                success : function(response)
                          {
                            if(response=="Error")
                            {
                                isUserLogged=false;
                                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                                alert("Authentication Failed"); 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isUserLogged=true;
                                machinenames = response;
                                server_names =[];
                                var temp1 = [],i=0,head='',id='';
                                for(var index in machinenames)
                                {
                                    head = machinenames[index];
                                    id = index;
                                    temp1.push({heading:head,machid:id});
                                }
                                if(temp1.length>0)
                                {
                                    server_names.push({'server_names':temp1});
                                }

                                $.mobile.changePage('#machines_page', {transition:'slide'});
                            }

                          },
                error   : function(error)
                          {
                            isUserLogged=false;
                            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                            alert(Error);
                            //alert("Error: Authentication Failed");

                          }
            });`

Comment: whats that ? People here would need more explanation on this. add detail regarding the exception you are getting and post your code.

Comment: This is a windows application functionality to check for user authentication. But i always got "system.collections.generic.dictionary 2 system.string system.object" Error

Comment: Why are you returning jQuery code as response. Just send one key successful => true/false if you just want to authenticate user. But if you want to still use this, try adding slashes before single quotes.